# Data Mapping for Importing data from external database

Tags: contacts

Can someone please guide me to the table/data templates for CiviCRM.  We are in the process of migrating from an existing relational Access database to CiviCRM and want to map related data to organisations, individuals, membership payments etc.  I have not been able to locate this in any documentation.

Thank you in advance for any pointers/help.

Graeme

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://doc.symbiotic.coop/dev/civicrm/latest/schema/ may offer what you need. If you click on any specific table it will show you all the children and if you keep scrolling down the page you will a 1 or 2 degree relational diagram

Answer (score 2):

During installation the CiviCRM are generated from xml files, and those will not always correspond 1-1 with the tables AFAIK.

You can find the xm definitions in the civicrm folder: civicrm/xml/schema.

Alternative is to use the API Explorer (Support/API Explorer in your CiviCRM menu) and do a getfields action for the entity? I would recommend using the API to do a migration anyway rather than moving into the tables directly.

Comment: Also check out the various Import menu links in CiviCRM and the related user guide docs. You might be able to import the data from csv files. While there is some generic database info at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/database/schema-design, I agree with Erik about using the api to make a smoother transition.

Comment: Also partly agree with the statement at https://docs.civicrm.org/dev/en/latest/framework/database/schema-design/#why-a-entity-relationship-diagram-may-not-be-helpful that `CiviCRM's Schema design is way too complex, with at least 150 tables and loads of Foreign Key Constraints linking tables together any such graphic or design document that tries to map out the CiviCRM database design would most likely bring more confusion than help`. Definitely for anyone starting out with CiviCRM.